# Sequence of numbers

Tags: number-sequence

I can not figure this sequence out. I have tried looking at the differences or differences of differences.

Fill in the dots:

83 80 84 83 88 95 ...

Choose one of the following answers:
87 95 91 83

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 :

> Remove 80 from all numbers, so you have : 0 3 4 3 8 15

Step2:

> Now index the numbers :
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
> 0 3 4 3 8 15

Step 3:

> Sum the numbers with indexes :

Sequence:

> 1 5 7 7 13 21

Result:

> You can see that this is a growing sequence, so I'd say **95** is next to keep it growing. 95 -> 15 at index 7 -> 22

Comment: Why is step 1 needed?

Comment: just to make it easier to represent the numbers, def not 'needed' :D

Comment: Sorry I mixed two numbers up. I corrected it.

Comment: @user3757341 demn! :'(

Comment: @toto: this is the correct sequence :).

Answer (score 0):

> 87. Probably not the correct answer and not a very logical explanation, but here goes nonetheless:

---

> Explanation 1: 
>  Adding the digits together gives us the sequence: 11 8 12 11 16 14.
>  The terms are going down and up alternately.
>  Next term must go up.
>  From the answers, only 8+7=15 is greater than 14. Hence, 87 is the answer.

---

> Explanation 2:
>  Reversing the digits gives us the sequence: 38 08 48 38 88 59.
>  The terms are going down and up alternately.
>  Next term must go up.
>  From the answers, only 87 -> 78 is greater than 59. Hence, 87 is the answer.

Comment: So I thought this: 84-83 =1, 88-84 =4 so: 88+7 = 95?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the rule is as simple (and stupid) as

> 83 every 3 numbers. Which would make the answer **83**. This might not be the answer that the question is looking for, but it applies and thus is correct nonetheless.